# Can みせ（店）be translated to something other than "shop"

Tags: translation, meaning, nuances, parsing

I've read a sample sentence that says:

あの　みせで　[食]{た}べましょう。

Apparently it translates to "Let's eat at that place", but what is the exact usage and meaning of みせで ?

> " [店]{みせ} is commonly translated as 'shop'.  Are there other meanings?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's two words, みせ + で.

みせ (店 in kanji) is a noun meaning *store*, *shop*, or sometimes *restaurant*. で is a particle which is similar in purpose to *at* or *in* in English. See: [Japanese Particle で](http://www.punipunijapan.com/japanese-particle-de/)

- あの: that
- みせ: restaurant
- で: at
- 食べましょう: let's eat